# Xcode errors after installing macports and wxWidgets

Tags: xcode, wxwidgets, deprecated, macports

I'm having trouble with Xcode 4.3.2, it has started displaying all kinf of deprecation errors whenever I try to compile an application or an .m file in Objective-C. The compilation works by the way but it's very slow and 200+ errors pop up.

This started right after I installed wxWidgets 3.0 using macports 
I used this commands :

```
sudo port install wxWidgets-3.0 +universal
sudo port select --set wxWidgets wxWidgets-3.0
```

after that I followed all the instructions on this page to configure Xcode : 
[creating-a-wxwidgets-xcode](http://zebratale.tumblr.com/post/11195706508/creating-a-wxwidgets-xcode-4-2-project-part-2)

So I added as explained the C++ flags, the linker flags, the I drag-and-dropped the libraries, I changed the plist file as explained, etc...

However when I tried to run the code it didn't work, it gave me this error :

> ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.0
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I decided to give up wxWidgets for a while and to move on another project. But whenever I tried to compile some Objective-C .m file I had these errors:

> In file included from
>   /Users/norman/Documents/wxwidget/eijbrsthbigrt/eijbrsthbigrt/eijbrsthbigrt-Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:70:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:25:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/cssmapple.h:30:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/cssmtype.h:142:5:
>   warning: 'CSSM_GUID' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>       CSSM_GUID Guid;
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/cssmtype.h:143:5:
>   warning: 'CSSM_VERSION' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>       CSSM_VERSION Version;
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/cssmtype.h:156:12:
>   warning: 'CSSM_GUID' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>       (const CSSM_GUID *ModuleGuid,

1) this is just an extract, there are 200+ errors

2) eijbrsthbigrt is the name of the project

I already tried to reset Xcode to defaults using `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`
but the errors are still there

I tried to uninstall macports : `sudo port -fp uninstall installed`
but I got this message:

> -bash: $: command not found

And I'd prefer not to uninstall it anyway. So I didn't insist on that.

I really don't know what to do now, because I don't really understand where the problem is coming from, so thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled macports, wxWidget and XCode, then reinstalled Xcode... It required a lot of time, but it solved my issue...